# 'Try This' Vector to Beep a word in sample dictionary. Programming Principles & Practice

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I am currently working through the book 'Programming Principles and Practice Using C++'. I am currently a little stuck on the 'Try This' exercise in chapter 4. Essentially the exercise to to take a list of words in a vector have another list of words in a separate vector called dislike  and beep out words that are on the dislike list. The insinuation from the chapter is that this should be achievable using the 'for' function and 'while' function. I am struggling to make this work. I have seen some solutions on-line but they use functions that the book has not yet covered and I would prefer to do the solution with the functions learnt so far, as to embed things. I am very much a novice so help very much appreciated.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
// simple dictionary: list of selected words
int main()
{
    vector<string>disliked={"Brocolli","Carrots","Cabbage","Sprouts"};
    vector<string>words;
        for(string temp; cin>>temp;)    //read whitespace separated words
            words.push_back(temp);      //put into vector
        cout << "Number of words:" << words.size() << '\n';

        sort(words);                    //sort the words


        for (int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i)
        for (int d=0; d<disliked.size(); ++d)
            if (words[i]!=disliked[d])
            if (i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i])
                cout << words[i] << "\n";
            else
                cout << "BEEP" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time if you put curly braces around the contents of your for-blocks and your if-blocks.  As it is, it's not easy to tell which statements are part of which for-loop, and which statements come after the end of the for-loop.   (Remember than in C++ whitespace has no semantic significance, so simply indenting the code doesn't affect the program's behavior)

Comment: Yes I think this is part of my problem but I have tried separating using the statements and despite various permutations I have not been able to get the desired result. Ideally it should list each word entered from the vector words variable 'once' but replace any matching the disliked variables with 'BEEP'. Behaviours I get are it repeating the words multiple times (because it is not terminating correctly and gets repeated through the second for statement) or doesn't do the replace with 'BEEP'. I think you are right but I can't see how to fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, however if anyone wants the answer with only what's been shown in the book so far, see below. Happy Coding!

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    vector<string> disliked = { "Broccoli", "Lettuce", "Tomato", "Pickle" };

    cout << "Enter word: ";
    for (string tempWord; cin >> tempWord;)
        words.push_back(tempWord);

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < disliked.size(); ++x)
            if (words[i] == disliked[x])
            {
                words[i] = "Bleep";
            }
        cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only beeping out words if its the same word as before.  All you are asked to do it replace the word with BEEP if it is something you dont like.  To keep it simple I replaced the words in one loop and then printed out the words in another.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

// simple dictionary: list of selected words
int main()
{
    vector<string> disliked = { "Brocolli", "Carrots", "Cabbage", "Sprouts" };
    vector<string> words;
    for( string temp; cin >> temp; ) {     //read whitespace separated words
        cout << "Adding " << temp << " to words.\n";
        words.push_back( temp );      //put into vector
    }
    cout << "Number of words:" << words.size() << '\n';

    std::sort( words.begin(), words.end() ); //sort the words

    for( int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i ) {
        for( int d = 0; d<disliked.size(); ++d ) {
            if( words[ i ] == disliked[ d ] ) {
                words[ i ] = "BEEP";
            }
        }
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i ) {
        cout << words[ i ] << "\n";
    }
}
```

P.S.
Words of advice you should almost always use brackets.  The only time I dont put brackets around if statements or loops is when it can fit on the same line.  If I have to make a new line to make the statement readable it always has brackets.

Comment: Thanks that's good advice. I think the example you have given overwrites the strings in the words vector that are also in the disliked vector with BEEP. If I want to keep the information in the words vector but just substitute with BEEP for the cout. What would be the best way to adjust things?

Comment: Yes it does overwrite.  If you wanted it to not overwrite the easiest thing would be to make a separate vector<string> if you are only using things up to chapter four in the book.  If I remember correctly when working through the book with my kids.

Comment: Otherwise you can use std::find on the disliked for each string in words and either cout BEEP or the string.  I can show you an example if you like.  If you found my answer helpful please upvote it and mark it as the answer the rep would help me.  Sorry for the slow reply I am getting ready for camping.

Comment: I will up-vote but I'm new so can't do this until I get more rep points. The std::find function has not yet been covered and I want to do the solution as efficiently as possible with the functions learn't so far. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sort `disliked` vector instead `words` vector.
In this way, you can reduce the test about 50%.

The following is an example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::string> disliked
    {"Brocolli", "Carrots", "Cabbage", "Sprouts"};

   std::vector<std::string>words
    {"Apples", "Carrots", "Plums", "Pears", "Brocolli", "Straberry"};

   std::cout << "Number of words:" << words.size() << '\n';

   std::sort(disliked.begin(), disliked.end()); //sort the disliked words

   std::cout << "Beeped words:";

   std::string  toCout;

   for ( unsigned i = 0U ; i < words.size() ; ++i )
    {
      toCout = words[i];

      for ( unsigned j = 0U ;    (j < disliked.size())
                              && (toCout >= disliked[j]) ; ++j )
         if ( toCout == disliked[j] )
            toCout = "BEEP!";

      std::cout << ' ' << toCout;
    }

   std::cout << std::endl;

   std::cout << "No beeped words:";

   for ( unsigned i = 0U ; i < words.size() ; ++i )
      std::cout << ' ' << words[i];

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting to see this variation. The book hasn't yet covered 'unsigned' and I want to do the solution as efficiently possible with the functions covered so far, but it is interesting to see.

Comment: @TrustNo1UK - you can use `int` instead of `unsigned`; but I think it's better use `unsigned` because `i` and `j` are compared with the `size()` of a couple of `vector`; and `size()` return a value of an unsigned type.

Comment: Great works perfectly. Now just got to work out the same thing using the while function. Tnx